# Finding the total hits and visitors in sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table appWebStats with following table fields appName ,userName ,dateTime

i tried

```
select Count(a.appName) as totalHits ,
       Count(a.distinct userName) as visitors ,
       a.dateTime 
from appWebStats a 
where date between time between '11-APR-12' and '14-APR-12'   
group by a.appName ,a.userName,a.dateTime;
```

but its returing 1 in all rows

what might be wrong here?

Edit:

what i want is

```
day      appname     totalHist uniqueVisitors
11         app1          56         5
11         app2          36         8
11         app3          26         7
12         app1          56         6
12         app2          36         8
13         app1          27         9
14         app2          34         4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query isn't doing what your question says.  If you want visitors by app, then group by the app and count the visitors:

```
select a.appName, 
       count(*) as visitors, 
       count(distinct a.userName) as uniqueVisitors
from table a
where datetime between '11-APR-12' and '14-APR-12'
group by a.appName;
```

If, instead, you wanted the number of apps and visitors per day, then use the time;

```
select trunc(a.datetime) as theday, 
       count(distinct a.appName) as numapps,
       count(distinct a.userName) as uniqueVisitors
from table a
where datetime between '11-APR-12' and '14-APR-12'
group by trunc(a.datetime)
order by 1;
```

EDIT:

I think the query you are looking for is:

```
select trunc(a.datetime) as theday, a.appName as numapps,
       count(*) as TotalHist,
       count(distinct a.userName) as uniqueVisitors
from table a
where datetime between '11-APR-12' and '14-APR-12'
group by trunc(a.datetime), a.appName
order by trunc(a.datetime), a.appName;
```

Comment: @Haider . . . You should play around with different queries to see what the aggregations do.  If you are going to use SQL, you should get a feel for how the language works.